# The tag wiki link short-code stopped working within comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, comments

I made a comment today on Stack Overflow and include the shortcode for a tag wiki link: `[tag:jquery-validate]`

These used to automatically be converted into a link looking like this: [jquery-validate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-validate)

However now, it simply shows up in the comment as this exact plain text: `[tag:jquery-validate]`

I didn't do anything different here, as all of my old comments using this same `tag:` short-code are also broken where they used to display the tag wiki link.

It seems to still work from within questions, at least here on meta: [jquery-validate](/questions/tagged/jquery-validate)

Comment: Probably related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215786/magical-site-hyperlinks-broken

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fat fingers on my side, trying to fix another issue with Minimarkdown.

Fix incoming!

---

Pushing out now, should be available network wide within 10 minutes.

Comment: And now I'm having to resist the urge to flag as "user posting identical answers to multiple questions" with http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215786/magical-site-hyperlinks-broken .

Comment: Same fix, different bug

Comment: Oh, I know. But that doesn't mean it overcomes the reflexes I've built up.