# Magical site hyperlinks broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, markdown, magic-links

I just tried leaving a comment for a user; normally when I type `[su]` in a comment, it [automatically expands to the correct Stack exchange site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments); however, that doesn't seem to be happening now.

The link to my comment is below:

[`@tom, [su] is the correct place for home networking questions`](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5798/unstable-network#comment8809_5798)

Is this a known bug?

Comment: Probably related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215785/the-tag-wiki-link-short-code-stopped-working-within-comments

Comment: [SO]  [meta] [edit] this is a test!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fat fingers on my side, trying to fix another issue with Minimarkdown.

Fix incoming!

---

Pushing out now, should be available network wide within 10 minutes.

Comment: [metase] testing 123

Comment: Hey why doesn't it work in this comment : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215786/magical-site-hyperlinks-broken#comment697563_215786

Comment: Why doesn't the meta link work? [meta]

Comment: @user689 because meta doesn't have a meta site. if you want to refer to this site, you need to use `[metase]`. `[meta]`, e.g. on super user, will work but will point to meta.su, not here.